# Question about supreme of infinity and supreme of empty set

Tags: analysis, real-numbers

Good morning, i have a few question about supreme.

1- ¿What happen with the supreme of infinity?
I think not have a supreme, because you need a upper bound, but i dont know.

2- ¿What happen with supreme of empty set?
Well, in this question i don't have idea how answer to this question, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I don't understand your first question. We usually take supremum of a set and not of an element ($\infty$ is not a number).)

The supremum of the empty set does not exist by definition:

(From Wikipedia)

> The supremum of a subset S of a partially ordered set T is **the least
>   element in T** that is greater than or equal to all elements of S, if
>   such an element exists.

As pointed out in the comment below, it is common to extend this definition to say that the supremum of the empty set of $=-\infty$. This might, of course, depend on the exact situation.

Comment: Actually one can extend consistently the definition of supreme by stating $\sup\emptyset:=-\infty$. In fact, $$\forall x\in \emptyset\quad x\leq-\infty .$$This makes reasonable the above *definition*.

Comment: @guestDiego: I edited. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the firts question is about see te infinity how a set.

Comment: The first question is ill-posed. One cannot understand what he means